# Background Function in awk

Tags: shell, awk

Is there a way to send a function to the background in pure awk?  Example:

```
function one() {
        system("sleep 5")
        print("Hello from One")
}

function two() {
        system("sleep 5")
        print("Hello from Two")
}

BEGIN {
        one()
        two()
}
```

As expected, the following happens:

```
<wait 5 seconds>
Hello from One
<wait 5 seconds>
Hello from Two
```

What I would *like* to happen is:

```
<wait 5 seconds>
Hello from One
Hello from Two
```

I would like to send the function to the background.  Is this possible or do I have to create a bash wrapper around it?  Thank you!

Comment: Just from reading your question I think `awk` might not be the right tool for your intent ;-)

Comment: Try python or similar ;-) Sorry for not answering your question but I assume any answer will be way too complicated to use and debug...

Comment: No. awk is a tool for reading text files. shell is a tool for manipulating process and files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is single-threaded, there's no way to run multiple codes concurrently.

For your simple example, you could use the shell's backgrounding:

```
function one() {
    system("(sleep 5; echo Hello from One) &");
}
function two() {
    system("(sleep 5; echo Hello from Two) &");
}
```

But if you want to run `awk` commands in the background, you can't do that.

Comment: Well, technically, he can. It would be just another instance of awk :)

Comment: Thanks everybody!  Guess I'll just stick with python in this case, then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, likely @dennis is right and `awk` is not a right tool for the task :) You may consider perl or other "programming languages".

Nevertheless if you're really "in the mood to have a lark", you may try to run a part of you program in a subshell. At least GNU awk does support such operational mode, see [info '(gawk)Two-way I/O'](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Two_002dway-I_002fO)

But well, even calling a Java callback from a C++ library loaded by a Python application is less "Dark Forces arts" than what you're going to do.